# Как заставить TypeScript увидеть проверку на ненулевое значение, выполненную внутри функции?

Tags: typescript

- Есть someFunction которая принимает значение типа **string**
- props.value имеет тип **null|undefined|string**
- чтобы проверить это дело есть удобный оператор **!=**.

[image: props.value != null]

Но я хочу **вынести проверку в отдельную функцию**, чтобы было так:
[image: isDefAndNotNull(props.value)]

Но в этом случае TypeScript не видит проверку. Можно ли его заставить подтянуть типы? (*оператор **!** не подойдёт*)

Answer (score 0):

В TS есть способ указать функцию, которая скажет TS, что переменная имеет конкретный тип. 
[Подробнее](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```
function isDefAndNotNull<T>(test: undefined | null | T): test is T {
  return test !== null && test !== undefined;
}

function doSomething(data: string) {
  return data;
}

interface Data {
  test?: string;
}

const data: Data = {
  test: 'test',
}

doSomething(data.test); // тут плохо
if(isDefAndNotNull<string>(data.test)) {
  doSomething(data.test); // тут хорошо
}
```

[Поиграться самому](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgEQKbAIJgCYBycUBIANmQDwAqAfABRQYpQBci4eWMYGeiAH0RhyZQYmoBKdkxbIUExAG8AUIkQAnDFBAaksqIgCEAXhPDRiAGRXEB42Y75uvPAG4VAXxUrQkWAiIeHAAynAAttoAFjwA5vR4AIZQiewsGnGSymqa2rpISSke3io8TBrAiRAYiAAKGnAADgqq6gYA-GlQGWCxxT4QCHKNDc3s9U0K5q12zGyIAOQGCwA0Xj4wwPSomDj4RCSilOlxDCOTAHQGklkzwWGRUDG99OfNV3OSxUA)

Comment: Спасибо. А как быть, если я использую только проверку TypeScript-а, а пишу код на чистом js используя js-doc?

Comment: Нашёл способ тут: https://dev.to/wes566/type-guards-in-javascript-using-jsdoc-comments-36l2 ThisMan, благодарю за помощь